# URL очищается от get-параметров

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3

На сайте очищаются url страниц от всех get-параметров, на всех. Делает из этого

```
/remont-balkonov-i-okon/?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={campaign_id} &utm_conтекст, выделенный жирным шрифтомtent={ad_id}_{source}&utm_term={keyword}&utm_others= {source_type}.{position_type}.{position}.{region_name}.{devi ce_type}
```

это

```
/remont-balkonov-i-okon
```

Я подозреваю, что дело в .htaccess, но признаюсь, я там ничего не понимаю. В общем потратив три часа пытаясь включать/выключать/править правила, что ни к чему не привело, я оправился сюда. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
##
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by your
# server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## No directory listings
<IfModule autoindex>
IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

## BEGIN EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/webp "access plus 1 year"

# HTC files (css3pie)
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 year"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"

# CSS and JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Cache-Control "public"
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
## END EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE ##
```

Comment: рекомендую привести вопрос в норм вид, исправить все опечатки, то что не используется в реальном запросе заменить на блоки, указывающие на это

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема решилась гораздо проще и даже не в .htaccess. В Joomla 3, чтобы получить нормальный ЧПУ необходимо включить SEF. Из-за чего, скорее всего, и очищается URL от лишнего. Но, чтобы не очищать от нужного, в данном случае было utm-метки, необходимо их добавить в системный плагин JL No Doubles, в данном случае достаточно было добавления **utm_source**.

Comment: Данный плагин не входит в комплект CMS и полагаю был дополнительно устнаовлен